# How to create a single JavaScript regex to match both length and multiple constraints?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to build a JavaScript regular expression with the following constraints:

- The input string needs to be at least 6 characters long
- The input string needs to contain at least 1 alphabetical character
- The input string needs to contain at least 1 non-alphabetical character

I'm seriously lacking a lookback feature in JavaScript. The thing I came up with:

```
((([a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z])|([^a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]))....)|
(.(([a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z])|([^a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]))...)|
(..(([a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z])|([^a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]))..)|
(...(([a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z])|([^a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])).)|
(....(([a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z])|([^a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])))
```

**This looks pretty long. Is there a better way?**

How I came to this:

1. Regex for alphabetical character is `[a-zA-Z]`
2. Regex for non-alphabetical character is `[^a-zA-Z]`
3. So I need to look for a `[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]` or `[^a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]`
    so `(([a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z])|([^a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]))`.
4. I need to check for *n* preceding characters and 6-*n* succeeding characters.

Comment: Why didn't you accept any of the answer. Is there still a problem ?

Comment: I always give people an opportunity to join the discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/^(?=.{6})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])/
```

This means:

`^` - start of the string
`(?= ... )` - followed by (i.e. an independent submatch; it won't move the current match position)
`.{6}` - six characters ("start of string followed by six characters" implements the "must be at least six characters long" rule)
`.*` - 0 or more of any character (except newline - may need to fix this?)
`[a-zA-Z]` - a letter (`.*[a-zA-Z]` therefore finds any string with a letter anywhere in it (technically it finds the last letter in it))
`[^a-zA-Z]` - a non-letter character

In summary: Starting from the beginning of the string, we try to match each of the following in turn:

- 6 characters (if we find those, the string must be 6 characters long (or more))
- an arbitrary string followed by a letter
- an arbitrary string followed by a non-letter

Comment: Pardon me, I'm a regex noob : Is the `^` at the start needed ?

Comment: Can you explain your regex a bit?

Comment: @dystroy Technically, no. But it's an optimization: If the regex engine isn't very clever, it will have to repeat the check at every position of the input string otherwise.

Comment: This has nothing to match, just look-aheads

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ No, it shouldn't.

Comment: @melpomene check out the question..`The input string needs to be at least 6 characters long`

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ As there is no $ at the end, I see no problem with {6}. The group doesn't have to match the whole string.

Comment: @dystroy ohh.. i missed `$`

Comment: Would `(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])` be faster?

Answer (score 3):

Use this regex...

```
/^(?=.{6,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z]).*$/
  -------- ------------- --------------
    ^          ^              ^
    |          |              |->checks for a single non-alphabet
    |          |->checks for a single alphabet
    |->checks for 6 to many characters
```

`(?=)` is a `zero width` look ahead which **checks** for a match.It **doesn't** consume characters.This is the reason why we can use multiple lookaheads back to back

Comment: Can you explain your regex a bit?

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker `(?=)` does look-ahead

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer to others, thus this doesn't need much explanation, I think the best way is to do

```
/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z]).{6,}$/
```

This starts at the beginning of the string, looks ahead for an alphabetical character, looks ahead for a non-alphabetical character and, in the end, it **finds** a string of 6+ chars, I think there's no need for lookaheads about length

Comment: Sure, you can always reorder the checks and remove the `(?= )` around the last one.

Comment: That's not just about reordering, it's about removing a redundant check and obtaining a string as a match. Using only lookaheads doesn't output a match string even if the input string matches.

Comment: OK, you can also always add `.*$` to the regex, which is effectively what you've done: 1) `/^(?=.{6})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z]).*$/`  2) Reorder: `/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])(?=.{6}).*$/`  3) Remove: `/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z]).{6}.*$/`  4) Fuse: `/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z]).{6,}$/`  If you'd skipped step 2, you'd've ended up with `/^(?=.{6})(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*[^a-zA-Z].*$/`, which works the same.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. My intended purpose with this answer was to match the whole string. I did it. Also @Some1.Kill.The.DJ did it, but I think the lookahead to check the string's length is useless and can be effortlessly joined with the string's match itself resulting in two lookaheads instead of three which I think (and might be disproved) results in slightly better performance.